# Mongoid: data selection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, exception, mongoid

I used rails3.2.3 with mongoid gem for mongodb database. I have following code
`user = User.find_by(username: login)` 
But this code gives error when the posted username not match with the any document's username. The error is like this:
`Problem:

  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 5010cdc81d41c8d30b0000405.
Summary:
  When calling User.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 5010cdc81d41c8d30b0000405 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 5010cdc81d41c8d30b0000405.
Resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.`

 I don't have any idea to solve this problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Resolution: Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.

Comment: Using where will return nil if any document does not match,
User.where(username: login).first

Otherwise just set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error = false as specified in the error

Comment: @Ranman and @ Dipil: How to set Mongoid.raise_not_found_error = false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use 
`user = User.find_or_create_by(username: login)`
instead of 
`user = User.find_by(username: login)`